# How to set date format to 24 hour in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am having problem displaying proper date in my app. When user sets 24 hour format 'ON' in his date time preferences..my app shows correct time but when 24 hour format is set to 'OFF' it shows nothing.

Here is the code I am using:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter       =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateStyle:style];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *temp            =   [formatter dateFromString:strDate];

[formatter setDateFormat:format];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *returnStr     =   [formatter stringFromDate: temp];
[formatter release];
NSLog(@"Return: %@", returnStr);

return returnStr;
```

Comment: Use yyyy not YYYY if you want the calendar year. YYYY doesn't match yyyy at the end of December.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Very simple try this:

**For 12 Hrs :** (hh:mm:ss)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

**For 24 Hrs :** (HH:mm:ss)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: also if you r running this code in iOS 7 then check system setting also.
goto setting -> general -> date & time -> switch off 24hr format

Answer (score 46):

Try this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
```

**HH** : 24 hour format

**hh** : 12 hour format

So in your case

```
//after conversion to date

if ON
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

if OFF
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Should use lowercase "yyyy"

Answer (score 15):

use this:

**Objective-C :**

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

**Swift 4.1**

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

after that your date won't modified.

Comment: Exactly, this known bug is [described by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html): "The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.".

Comment: Not a bug, that's a feature. Although it's a bit confusing as to how to properly handle it.

Comment: This answer is the most correct, using HH with a 12 hour clock setting will give AM/PM in the output string.

Answer (score 5):

Set the locale of the dateFormatter as following. It should sove your problem.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"]; 
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Should be lowercase "yyyy", uppercase is for ["week of year-based calendars"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)